# nodeJS, JOB scheduling

Tags: node.js, scheduling, jobs

I am implementing one web Server which will do multiple tasks, for that I am planning to use cluster on 8 core server.
The tasks are as below:
need to poll some statistics data from some server every 1 second and store that data in local  redis server.
Need to access multiple servers to send the response of single request coming from web client.
Some request may be of video streaming.
For that I am planning to make it cluster based to utilize multiple cores. 
So is there any way in cluster to specify "this worker should do this work specifically", If yes, then I can distribute the work among multiple workers, like web request be served by n1 to n2 workers and polling by 1st worker always etc.

Or what you think I should follow to get best performance.

Regards,
-M-

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with Kue where subscribers were added on different worker-processes. It runs on Redis so it might be of interest. But in your case, I'd consider using some kind of CRON setup. You can still use redis pub/sub feature on different processes.

Kue:
http://learnboost.github.com/kue/

CRON based:
http://www.romansky.me/2012/10/20/distributed-scheduled-queue-with-redis/